# Sources that support not taking food from the table before the rabbi makes kiddush?

Tags: kiddush, derech-eretz-manners

To me this seems like an obvious sense of basic respect to the community but it doesn't seem like everyone thinks as I do and looking for sources that support that this is a practice that should not be done. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a matter addressed in Torah sources?

Comment: Yes would be so nice to find a source to yell at the guy taking all the rogelach before anyone else but I don't think this is a halacha

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. You just have to cover your mezonos. What actual harm does this cause to justify your feelings?

Comment: It's a lack of derech eretz

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara (Pesachim 100b) says that it is better not to bring the table with the bread until after Kiddush, In order to indicate that it was brought in honor of Shabbos, but because nowadays our tables are bigger and hard to move around, it is okay to just have it covered, but perhaps it is still better not to have the Mezonos right in front of you (or at least not in your hands) until after Kiddush, for this reason

Comment: There are indeed opinions that mezonot needs to be covered before kiddush for this reason, but apparently the shul in question is not holding of them (maybe it should switch to)